# List files in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

Admittedly, I'm new to programming and been trying to figure this out for far too long...  I need to (by button click) pull all files from a particular folder, including all sub-folders. My two datatable columns are "FileName" & "FilePath".  FileName should show just the file name. FilePath should show the entire path, including c:  Any help appreciated!

```
 string Dpath = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\Plot Files";
 DataTable d = new DataTable();
 DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Dpath);
 DataRow drawingTableRow = d.NewRow();
 foreach (FileInfo fi in DirInfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
 { 
     drawingTableRow = d.NewRow();
     drawingTableRow["FileName"] = fi.FullName;
     drawingTableRow["FilePath"] = fi.Name;
     d.Rows.Add(drawingTableRow);
 }
```

Comment: where you are stuck?

Comment: It seems you forgot to add columns to your data table.  `d.Columns.Add("FileName");    d.Columns.Add("FilePath");`

Answer (score 0):

I Think the Problem you are facing is

> Cannot found column `"FileName"` In the
>   line`drawingTableRow["FileName"]`

Since you have not define the column names of the table. So change the declaration of the DataTable `d` like the following will solve the issue:

```
DataTable d = new DataTable();
d.Columns.Add("FileName");
d.Columns.Add("FilePath");
```

I Will suggest you another option to fill the DataTable, Take a look into the code below:

```
DataTable FilesTable = new DataTable();
FilesTable.Columns.Add("FileName");
FilesTable.Columns.Add("FilePath");
DataRow dRow;
string yourPath = @"your path here";
string searchPattern = "*.*";
var resultData = Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(x => new { FileName = Path.GetFileName(x),FilePath = x });

foreach (var item in resultData)
{
    dRow = FilesTable.NewRow();
    dRow["FileName"] = item.FileName;
    dRow["FilePath"] = item.FilePath;
    FilesTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SOOO much guys. Both of those answers (partially) helped fixed my problem.
I must add for anybody else having the same problem.... I discovered that one additional item was necessary to display my data:

```
 dataGridView2.DataSource = d;
```

Admittedly I don't completely understand why this pieces of code is necessary since I'm binding the table from my datagridview... but this was the last piece of my puzzle.
Thanks again guys!